# How do I tokenize this input line with variable types such that I can decide the size(s) of the struct holding my information?

Tags: c, regex, unix, bison, flex-lexer

This is a multiple part question. Firstly my input file will look like this:

```
category Shoes brand:char[50],cost:int
category Shirts brand:char[20],cost:int
```

My questions are:

a.) How do I break up the line at `:` only after the category name? `Shoes` or `Shirts` in these cases.

b.) How would I write my Bison parser such that I would be determining the variables (eg. `char[30]`) of the struct that would hold the information for each line?

If these questions seem too localized, I'd appreciate it if I could be guided to some resources that could help me do the same

Comment: Please be careful to tag your questions properly.  The Flex tag is used for the Adobe/Apache framework.  Gnu-flex is used for the lexical analyzer.

Comment: Can you provide an example of exactly what your input looks like (I'm not sure what char[20] means precisely). Is your goal here to extract the values of the category, the brand and the cost and then populate a struct?

Comment: (a.) Please clarify what you mean by break up the line at ':'. Does it mean that in the input file, the description between category name and cost can span multiple lines , but category followed by category name have to be on one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are far too many missing details.  For instance, can "int" be used as a category name?  How do you plan to store the data you parse?

Still, an initial sketch would be something like this for the parser:

```
%token CATEGORY "category"
       EQ       "="
       COLON    ":"
       COMMA    ","
       LBRA     "["
       RBRA     "]"
       INT      "int"
       CHAR     "char"
       ID
       NATURAL
;
%%    
categories:
  category
| categories category
;

category:
  "category" ID fields
;

fields:
  field
| fields "," field
;

field:
  ID ":" type
;

type:
  "char"
| "int"
| type "[" NATURAL "]"
;
```

and this for the scanner:

```
%%
"category"   return CATEGORY;
"="          return EQ;
":"          return COLON;
","          return COMMA;
"["          return LBRA;
"]"          return RBRA;
"int"        return INT;
"char"       return CHAR;
[a-zA-Z]+    return ID;
[0-9]+       return NATURAL;
[ \n\t]+     continue;
```

Answer (score 2):

(b.) I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. I assume you want to parse each entry in the input file and store the info in a struct. Category and Brand would be strings and cost would be an int. You want to know beforehand, the length of the strings, so you can assign a variable to hold the parsed value (such as char[20]).

Why not use C++ strings? Then you don't have to declare the length . Example [here](http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html#11).
If you must use C, you can just have a char * and allocate the string on heap using malloc.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) has a reasonable, simple example that can be a guide to what you're trying to do. A complete general procedure for writing a flex/bison parser is:

1. Decide what the tokens are, write a regex and choose an identifier for each (as @akim has done in his flex/bison code).
2. Write a LALR(1) Context Free Grammar for the "legal" input you're trying to parse.  @akim has given you a leg up on this one.
3. Design a target data structure to hold the parser result.  This is the key thing missing in your post.  If you are just trying to compute a single integer size, then you're done.  If you need to pass more detail on for further processing, you'll want some kind of record/enumeration/list structure, which is normally called an *abstract syntax tree* or AST even though it's often not really a tree.
4. Implement the AST (if necessary) data structure including constructor functions like `CATEGORY_NODE make_category(enum category_e cat);`.  These constructors will be called by the parser.
5. Implement the tokens in a flex scanner program file with no action code.
6. Implement the CFG in the bison parser program file with no action code.
7. Build a test frame and a test suite and test that the scanner and parser read legal inputs  and reject bad ones.  So far the program does nothing else.  This is where @akim's code is now.
8. Decide what data must be associated with each token, if any. For example, an unsigned number's value would be its magnitude returned from the scanner as an `unsigned int`.  An identifier's value will be a string.  But a bracket `[` has no value at all. Use these types to create the bison `%union` directive to accept values from the scanner.  Add these as `<union_field>` tags to the respective `%token` directives.  See the example for the `@union` used there, which has two token value types.
9. Fix the `flex` scanner by adding an `#include "foo.tab.h"` at the top and adding action code to return the correct token value for the respective tokens.  At this point everything should compile and run again, but still do nothing.  Again refer to the example.
10. Now implement data handing in the parser.  You'll be using the dollar `$n` and `$$` directives and adding `<union_field>` type tags to grammar nonterminals to move data among the grammar rules and finally calls to the constructors for your AST structure to build the structure as the input is read (or to increment the integer if that's all it is). This is where experience and deeper knowledge of LALR parsers is helpful.  The later examples in the `Bison` documentation are another reference for this part.  If you hit roadblocks, come back with specific questions.
11. Run the tests again and print the resulting AST in a form you can verify.  XML works well for this.

Now I'm sure someone will observe that this fully general approach is overkill for what you've asked so far.  It depends .Your current input is so simple that you could probably hand-write a little *ad hoc* parser more quickly, not using flex or bison at all.

However if the program you're writing is likely to be in use for a while and to change over time, having all the machinery of a general parser in place at the beginning can make life much easier.  Thinking about program input as a real language rather than just raw data can lead you to create functionality that otherwise would never have occurred to you.